# How to generate a bool 2D arrays from two 1D arrays using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, comparison, vectorization

I have two arrays `a=[1,2,3,4]` and `b=[2,3]`. I am wondering is there an efficient way to construct a boolean 2D array `c` (2D matrix, i.e. 2*4 matrix) based on array element comparsions, i.e. `c[0,0] = true` iff `a[0] == b[0]`. The basic way is to iterate through all the elements of `a` and `b`, but I think there maybe a better using `numpy`. I checked `numpy`reference, but could not find a routine could exactly that.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you can extend the dimensions of `b` with [`np.newaxis/None`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) to form a `2D` array and then perform equality check against `a`, which will bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a vectorized solution, like so -

```
b[:,None] == a
```

Sample run -

```
In [5]: a
Out[5]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [6]: b
Out[6]: array([2, 3])

In [7]: b[:,None] == a
Out[7]: 
array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: the code works great, I am wondering what if I want a 4*2 matrix instead of a 2*4 matrix shown in the example, what should I do?

Comment: @daiyue Extend `a` in that case and compare against `b` : `a[:,None] == b`.